# Is there a way to pre increment by more than 1 in Java?

Tags: java

In Java you can do a post increment of an integer i by more that one in this manner:

`j + i += 2`.

I would like to do the same thing with a pre increment.

e.g `j + (2 += i) //This will not work`

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Actually i += 2 is a pre increment. It increments i first and returns the result.

Comment: That is not what pre and post increment mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a confusion in terminology going on, but `+=` is ***not*** a post or pre-increment operator! Java follows the C/C++ definition of post-increment/pre-increment and they are well defined in the standard as *unary* operators. `+=` is a shortcut for a *binary* operator. It evaluates to this:

```
lvalue1 += 5 ;
// is really (almost)
lvalue1 = lvalue1 + 5;
```

The assembler for the instruction doesn't look exactly like the binary version but at the level your using Java you do not see that.

The post-increment/pre-increment are unary operators that function kind of like this:

```
i++ ; // is something like _temp = i; i = i + 1; return temp;
++i;  // is something like i = i + 1; return i;
```

This is just an example of how it works, the byte code doesn't translate too multiple statements for the post-increment case.

In your example, you could say a post-increment occurs but really, its just an increment. which is why I believe you have made the (incorrect) leap that it might be possible to have a pre-increment version of the same operation. But such a thing does not exist in C, C++, or Java.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the increment statement in parentheses. For example, the following will output `pre: 2`:

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(
    ((i+=2) == 0)
    ? "post: " + i : "pre: " + i);
```

However, writing code like this borders on obfuscation. Splitting up the statement into multiple lines will significantly improve readability.

Comment: What would this do? int x = 1;
  int y = (x += 2 );

Comment: @djna Just test it ;). `y = x = 3`.

Comment: I did, that's why asked the question.  y gets the post value. I thought it was worth contrasting with the use in the conditional expression.

Comment: Suddenly I'm confused by the answer. We get "pre: 2" printed. But what does that mean? The value of (i+=2) is 2, not == 0, so the conditional is seeing the value **after** the increment. Which I would have called "post".

Comment: @djna y getting the *post* value means (x+=2) is a *pre* -increment. I don't think there's an analogue way to post-increment by more than one.

Comment: @djna No, the *pre* and *post* refer to the time of the increment, not which value we get in the final result.

Comment: Aha, terminology. Agree with your conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
int increment = 42;
int oldI = i;
i += increment;
result = myMethod(oldI);
// Rest of code follows.
```

But why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `+=` is pre increment. If you want post increment simply create wrapper with postInc method which will do this. If you really need this it would be more readable than parenthesis.